# JavaFX: Store TextField in HashMap

Tags: javafx, hashmap, textfield

Trying to store a TextField in a HashMap like this:

```
TextField textfield;
Map<String, TextField> map = new HashMap<String, TextField>();
        for(int row = 0; row < RowLim; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < ColLim; col++) {
                String name = row+""+col;
                map.put(name,textfield = new TextField());
            }
        }
```

It's a Sudoku solver meant to teach me some about JavaFX. Each textfield is displayed in a gridpane and is supposed to have a Key corresponding to its placement in my map. However when I make some input in any textfield and print it I get a null. I don't think I have the right idea about how textfield works, but can't really see any other solution, so I'm stuck. I use textfield.getText() method when printing.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it eventually by adding a new HashMap that retrieves each textfield.getText() value and stores it as a String. Adding a try-catch statement to exclude all null-statements. It worked perfectly. Here's my code:

```
Map<String, String> numbermap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(Map.Entry<String,TextField> me : map.entrySet()) {
            numbermap.put(me.getKey(),me.getValue().getText());
        }
        try {
            for(Map.Entry<String,String> me : numbermap.entrySet()) {
                //Code to use inputvalues from each textfield...
            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Gives null");
        }
```